# Ignore field when applying form data to case class

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

i have encountered following problem.

I have following case class that is container for data from the form and it's used to push data do mongo.

```
case class InActiveUser(login: String, password: String)
```

And it's form.

```
implicit val registerForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "login" -> nonEmptyText,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText,
      "passwordMatch" -> nonEmptyText
    )(InActiveUser.apply)(InActiveUser.unapply))
```

The question is, how can i ignore the passwordMatch Value and only use it for validation, do i have to write custom Apply method?

Comment: You can just write `((l, p, p2) => InActiveUser(l, p))` instead of `(InActiveUser.apply)`